# Calculating "weighted" averages

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, math

In my database, I have a `series` table:

```
series_id    | series_name        | series_avg_rating
-----------------------------------------------------
1            | The 100            | null
2            | The walking dead   | null
```

Users can "rate" series (0.01 to 5.00). Ratings are registered like so:

```
ratings_user_id  | ratings_series_id | ratings_rating
-----------------------------------------------------
1                | 1                 | 4.50
4                | 2                 | 2.50
```

Now, in order to calculate the `series_avg_rating` column for the series table, I am currently using the following query:

`SELECT AVG(ratings_rating) FROM ratings WHERE ratings_series_id = 1;`

This works. But the main problem is, that a user could rate the series with a 5, and the show would pop to the #1 position of highest rated show. This is not what I want.

I would like to figure out a way to make it so that the ratings make more sense, and only the best would have the highest registered rating.

Does anyone know a good way of doing this? Is there a basic formula or query to retrieve the "weighted" average?

Comment: So you want to give shows that have a lower amount of ratings a lower position in the rankings? But would a show with 1 rating at 5 stars still be worse than a show with 1000 ratings of 1 star? There has to be a tipping point somewhere. There is no general rule for that, but I suggest you take COUNT(ratings_rating) into account.

Comment: @DirkScholten A show rated with 1 star 1000 times is terribly rated. Meaning it should have lower position in the rankings.

Comment: Most places that do ratings just hide the ratings of something until it's gotten at least X ratings where X needs to be fine-tuned to a value which you're confident enough is representative. The "cold start" problem is still quite an open problem

Comment: @Musa Yeah I get that 1000 ratings of 1 star is really bad, that's why I picked such an extreme example. My point was to figure out at what point the single 5 star rating should be above multiple worse ratings. Try to figure that out and then maybe you can decide on a nice formula that would calculate this.

Comment: You can also sort ratings by stars and then by number of ratings used to calculate the stars. The single 5 star rating will still be high up but after all 5 star ratings with more than 1 rater.

Comment: why don't you just calculate the sum of the rating, no need to get the average, sounds logical to me